# How to target suffixes in scss at hover

Tags: css, sass, next.js

I'm working on a nextJS project using SCSS and I have an issue to target the child at hover and focus:

```
.accordion {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 4rem auto;
  width: 90%;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  background: #f4f4f4;

  &__copy {
    display: none;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    color: gray;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
   
    &--open {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  &:hover {
   // How to target &__copy?
    &__copy {
     // code
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly — you aim to apply some code to `.accordion__copy` when focusing on/hovering over **its parent** `.accordion`.

If so, the following should do it:

```
 &:hover > & {
   // How to target &__copy?
    &__copy {
     // code
    }
  }
```

If your aim is to target the child when hovering over **the child itself** then this should fix it:

```
 &__copy {
    display: none;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem 2rem 1.5rem;
    color: gray;
    line-height: 1.6;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
   
    &--open {
      display: block;
    }

  &:hover {
     // code
  }
}
```